# Is postid a derived form or an archaic form of post?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, old-latin, plautus

I pondered this since reading some Plautus. It seems similar to postea (post ea), just being in singular (so post id?), or perhaps it is the obsolete earlier form of post itself. Just curious if there is a definite consensus on this word's etymology.

Comment: Can you give an example of where you found postid? Searching Plautus, I'm only seeing postidea, not postid on its own.

Comment: Sure, I encountered it in the prologue of Casina, lines 32-34: Deiphilus hanc graece scripsit, postid rursum denuo latine Plautus cum latranti nomine. (Text from Loeb Classical Library)

Comment: Interesting! I don't have a proper answer yet, but I do want to note that other editions have _post id_ there.

Comment: Ah! It mostly looks like a typo! I ran the form, postid, in the Latin concordance tool and found no match, but did find plenty of the form, post id, with that space. But this does beg an additional question: How does postea become generally a compound and not post id?